# PowerShell does not invoke REST API correctly

Tags: rest, powershell

I have a POST REST API as follows

```
http://9e459ba0.ngrok.io/SizeAuditor/RecordBaselineData
```

It is invoked with this JSON body as payload, and inserts data correctly to the required database.

```json
[
    {
        "projectName" : "fab",
        "commitHash" : "4251CA37541CE059CF354CCD7F1E2AAFD6C2342F",
        "size" :
        {
            "fileName" : "hosts",
            "fileSize" : 100
        }
    }
]
```

However, when I use powershell, as follows, the API gets invoked but returns with an error, which leads me to believe that the payload is not sent through correctly.

```bsh
$paramsJson = '[ { "projectName" : "fab", "commitHash" : "4251CA37541CE059CF354CCD7F1E2AAFD6C2342F", "size" : { "fileName" : "hosts", "fileSize" : 100 } } ]'

$params = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $paramsJson

echo $params

$responseData = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://9e459ba0.ngrok.io/SizeAuditor/RecordBaselineData -Method Post -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $params;

echo $responseData
```

I have tried printing out the `$params` object and also converted it back to JSON using `$params | ConvertTo-Json` and it seems to be in the correct format, I expect the API to receive. Please suggest what I am doing incorrectly in the PowerShell.

**EDIT:**

The error message is as follows, and fails at a certain functions (I have written the REST API as well). However, I would feel it's something related to the payload format, and not the actual data that is being passed, since the JSON format of this passed over Postman succeeds.

```
Invoke-RestMethod : "An error has occurred.Object reference not set to an
instance of an object.System.NullReferenceException
   at OneShip.Service.Workers.SizeAuditor.AzureTableStorageProvider.InsertBaselineDataIntoDatabase(BaselineData[] baselineData) in D:\\MyService\\Service\\src\\Workers\\SizeAuditor\\AzureTableStorageProvider.cs:line 52\u000a
   at OneShip.Service.SizeAuditorController.<RecordBaselineData>d__7.MoveNext() in D:\\MyService\\Service\\src\\SizeAuditorController.cs:line 76\u000a
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\u000a
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\u000a
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\u000a
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()\u000a
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\u000a
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\u000a
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\u000a
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\u000a
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\u000a
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\u000a
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\u000a
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\u000a
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\u000a
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\u000a
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\u000a
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
At line:1 char:17
+ ... sponseData = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://9e459ba0.ngrok.io/SizeAudi ...
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Comment: This indicates a null reference exception

Comment: If you did write the API yourself, why can't you debug it?

Comment: Looks to me like your backend doesn't like the data you're passing to it. This doesn't appear to be an issue on the PowerShell side.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers but the same json when passed over postman works. So, doesn't it have to be something to do with the powershell?

Comment: Does Postman pass the exact same, unmodified JSON to your API?

Comment: Why are you using `ConvertFrom-Json`? Did you try without that, using `-Body $paramsJson` ?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler wow! that works. Now I am even more curious as to why $params does not work. I tried comparing $params | ConvertTo-Json with $paramsJson, and they are pretty identical. I want to post an edit with these comparisons, but looks like something with the code formatting of the existing post, does not let me post any more.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, that works. But I tried printing out the $params | ConvertTo-Json and compared it against $paramsJson, and they look pretty identical, except for spacing between member name and the colon. like "fieldName":"value" as compared with "fieldName" : "value". Still curious, as to why $params does not work.

Comment: @LearnToImprove $params is an array of objects, and Invoke-restmethod doesn't know what to do with it. It tries to cast it to a string, and that comes out blank, and it sends an empty string to the webserver. They may look identical when PS renders them on screen but they are completely different data types